# How to use GAN model after the training

Tags: testing, generative-adversarial-network

Do we need to normalize the data (as we normalize during the GAN' training) during testing procedure?

Answer (score 1):

There is no testing phase in GANS as we normally have in other neural networks like CNN etc. GAN generator models are evaluated based on the quality of the images generated, often in the context of the target problem domain.

Ways to Evaluate GANS:

Manual Evaluation:
Many GAN practitioners fall back to the evaluation of GAN generators via the manual assessment of images synthesized by a generator model which is known as manual way of evaluation.
This involves using the generator model to create a batch of synthetic images, then evaluating the quality and diversity of the images in relation to the target domain.

This may be performed by the researcher or practitioner themselves.

Qualitative GAN Evaluation:
Qualitative measures are those measures that are not numerical and often involve human subjective evaluation or evaluation via comparison.

Five qualitative techniques for evaluating GAN generator models are listed below.

Nearest Neighbors.
Rapid Scene Categorization.
Rating and Preference Judgment.
Evaluating Mode Drop and Mode Collapse.
Investigating and Visualizing the Internals of Networks.

Quantitative GAN Generator Evaluation:
Quantitative GAN generator evaluation refers to the calculation of specific numerical scores used to summarize the quality of generated images.

Twenty-four quantitative techniques for evaluating GAN generator models are listed below.

Average Log-likelihood
Coverage Metric
Inception Score (IS)
Modified Inception Score (m-IS)
Mode Score
AM Score
Frechet Inception Distance (FID)
Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD)
The Wasserstein Critic
Birthday Paradox Test
Classifier Two-sample Tests (C2ST)
Classification Performance
Boundary Distortion
Number of Statistically-Different Bins (NDB)
Image Retrieval Performance
Generative Adversarial Metric (GAM)
Tournament Win Rate and Skill Rating
Normalized Relative Discriminative Score (NRDS)
Adversarial Accuracy and Adversarial Divergence
Geometry Score
Reconstruction Error
Image Quality Measures (SSIM, PSNR and Sharpness Difference)
Low-level Image Statistics
Precision, Recall and F1 Score

Hope it will make some sense.

Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-evaluate-generative-adversarial-networks/